# How can I bind events to the appended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to show an error message using the jquery effect `fadeTo` and tried to hide the message by appending a button and using fadeout but doesn't seem to work.

What I did was:

```
$("#sub_error")
  .fadeTo(200, 0.1, function()
  {
    $("#sub_error")
      .html(error.join("<br/><br/>"))
      .append('<br/><input type="button" name="err_ok" id="err_ok" value="ok">')
      .addClass('subboxerror')
      .fadeTo(900,1);
  });

$("#err_ok").click(function() 
{
  $("#sub_error").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

What am I doing wrong, could someone help me?

Comment: at what point does it stop to work?

Comment: Hmm after rereading the quesiton I'm not so sure either anymore.. I don't know if my answer helps.

Comment: when i click the button the div element having id should have faded out but it does not , and i don't know why? may be it's not accessing the appended button "err_ok"

Comment: You realize that you're basically reimplementing a (simpler) version of the jQuery UI dialog widget here.  Generally I would use this widget instead and make it modal for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the #err_ok element doesn't exist at first so the .click() handler is not applied to it.

You can solve this by putting

```
$("#err_ok").click(function () {
  $("#sub_error").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

in a function and call the function after creating the element in the DOM.

Edit: This should be a full solution:

```
$("#sub_error").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
    $("#sub_error")
      .html(error.join("<br/><br/>"))
      .append('<br/><input type="button" name="err_ok" id="err_ok" value="ok">')
      .addClass('subboxerror')
      .fadeTo(900, 1);
    bindEvents();
});

function bindEvents() {
    $("#err_ok").click(function() {
        $("#sub_error").fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```

There is also a "[live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)" function that binds events to future created DOM elements too.

Comment: You could also just bind the event to err_ok in the function where it is created.

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas , it worked , i was suspecting may be it is not accessing the appended button ... thank you ;)

Comment: No problem. I had the same problem before, took me a while to figure out :-)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there are filed tickets about fadeTo/fadeOut bugs on the JQuery bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  One, you can append the click handler to the element after it is inserted:

```
$("#sub_error").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
    $("#sub_error")
      .html(error.join("<br/><br/>"))
      .append('<br/><input type="button" name="err_ok" id="err_ok" value="ok">')
      .addClass('subboxerror')
      .fadeTo(900, 1)
      .find('#err_ok')
      .click( function() {
        $("#sub_error").fadeOut("slow");
      });
});
```

Or two, you can use the live event handler so that any element with the "err_ok" id will get the click handler whenever it's created.

```
$('#err_ok').live('click', function() {
    $('#sub_error').fadeOut('slow');
});
```